# Input binding not working on custom made angular library

Tags: html, angular, input, angular7

I've built an Angular library that I can import into outside applications. Withing my library exists a component called 'MainComponent' that has a single @Input variable for 'objectId'.

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "main-component",
  templateUrl: "../templates/app.html",
  styleUrls: ["../styles/app.css"],
  providers: []
})

export class MainComponent {

  @Input() objectId: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log("MainComponent constructor running!! objectId: " + this.objectId);
    // 'objectId' is undefined in the constructor
  }
}
```

When I import the library into another project, I use the MainComponent like this:

```
<main-component [objectId]="123456"></main-component>
```

However, objectId is always `undefined`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - is there something different I must do since this is a custom made Angular library?

Comment: Is it also `undefined` in `ngOnInit` and/or other lifecycle hooks?

Comment: I tested against ngAfterViewInit and it is still undefined.

Comment: You can check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgtoa2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts) and try to find what you are doing differently.

Comment: Also, please note that using `[objectId]="abcdef"` will give `undefined`. We assume that you actually pass `[objectId]="123456"`.

Comment: I do use actual numbers e.g. [objectId]="123456". Since 'objectId' is a string, shouldn't [objectId]="abcdef" technically also work?

Comment: No, because the square brackets tell Angular that it should evaluate the expression `abcdef`, which is `undefined` (unless you define the property `abcdef` in your component class). To bind a literal string, you can use `objectId="abcdef"` or `[objectId]="'abcdef'"`.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with an nx lib . Maybe it is an issue with custom libraries. Still udefined even after debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objectId` is a string, and as in input you can pass as either:

```html
<!-- use non-bracket notation to pass as string -->
<main-component objectId="123456"></main-component>
```

or

```html
<!-- use bracket notation with single quotes to pass as string -->
<main-component [objectId]="'123456'"></main-component>
```

Comment: I don't think that it would look for a variable with the name `123456`. It would evaluate the expression `123456`, which would result in the corresponding number. That is why the original code should work with `123456` but not with `abcdef`.

Answer (score 2):

`objectId` is `undefined` when queried in the constructor but should be defined if you were to implement the `OnInit` interface and look at it in `ngOnInit()`. Input passing doesn't happen when the component class is constructed, it's somewhere further down the lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is still undefined.

Comment: Are you initially passing the input as `undefined` and switching it later? If so you might need to implement `OnChanges` and check new values in `ngOnChanges()`